# iOS app get killed in background if spend more than 30 seconds, iOS 13 mostly

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, background, ios13

I have an iOS app which uses CoreLocation and WiFi SSID information. My app was working fine until iOS 13 arrived but since then it's giving me a lot of issues especially when app goes in background. I have been using one timer in background as background task which also not work after 30 seconds and especially app got killed in background in the same time frame. I have seen some people saying that iOS 13 has been strict for background task and timing but I still have not found any direct references or links by apple which supports this claims. Is there anyone else facing the same issues then please share your insights. Thanks

I have one background task for timer:

```
  var bgTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?
  var updateTimer: Timer?

  func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    bgTask = application.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "MyTask", expirationHandler: {() -> Void in

       if let bgTask = self.bgTask {

       application.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
       self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier(rawValue: convertFromUIBackgroundTaskIdentifier(UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid))

       }

    })

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in

        self.updateTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.checkNetworkStatus), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    })

  }

 @objc func checkNetworkStatus() {
    print("Timer calledddd")
 }
```

Comment: So what's the resolution? Which API could I use to fire timer after, let's say, 10 minutes after app went to background?

Comment: Honestly, not much idea on this but you can look into this thread https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/114859

Comment: https://basecamp.temenos.com/s/question/0D52K000048U558/timer-not-firing-when-app-is-in-background-in-ios

Comment: well, if you're playing background audio - timers will work. This is my workaround, not sure how useful it would be for you (my app is about background music player).

Answer (score 9):

The name background task is somewhat misappropriate.

Specifically, `beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:)` doesn’t actually start any sort of background task, but rather it tells the system that you have started some ongoing work that you want to continue even if your app is in the background.

You still have to write the code to create and manage that work.

**So it’s best to think of the background task API as raising a “don’t suspend me” assertion.**

iOS 13 puts strict limits on the total amount of time that you can prevent suspension using background tasks.

iOS 13 has reduced the from-the-foreground value to 30 seconds.

**a. 3 minutes, when your app has moved from the foreground to the background**

**b. 30 seconds, when your app was resumed in the background**

You can get a rough estimate of the amount of time available to you by looking at `UIApplication() backgroundTimeRemaining` property.

Further info [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623031-beginbackgroundtask) and [here](https://medium.com/swlh/handling-background-tasks-in-ios-13-67f717d94b3d).

You may want to consider a different API to achieve your goals.

Comment: @WoodstockThanks for the prompt reply, I understand how this beginBackgroundTask works which is not background task itself but as you mentioned as 'don't suspend me' kind of assertion. However, what you mean by 'from-the-foreground value to 30 seconds' ? Also, I have seen that I never get 3 minutes of time when I move from foreground to background and it kills my app within 30 seconds only. do you have any alternatives in your mind for this??

Comment: do you think I can have timer which can work more than 30 seconds when I go into background ?

Comment: What does your app do specifically? Are you looking to scan for SSID in background?

Comment: yes, I am scanning and checking status of connected SSID and once I get my desired SSID then I am sending local notification.

Comment: @Woodstock can you please specify some API to achive the same?